# Preg_match_all Multiple Content

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

i want to get multiple data from a site with preg_match_all function. But the function does not work when I use this regex command (. *?) multiple.

It's not a json. I get data from the source code of any instagram profile. ex: view-source:https: //www.instagram.com/ziynetaki When you open the link you can see the following code. script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = .....

i've tried:

```
$display = '#__typename":"GraphImage","id":"(.*?)","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"(.*?)"}}]},"shortcode":"(.*?)","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":(.*?)},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":(.*?),"dimensions":{"height":(.*?),"width":(.*?)},"display_url":"(.*?)","edge_liked_by"#i';

preg_match_all($display, $url, $dop);
print_r($dop);
```

and output is null:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) [3] => Array ( ) [4] => Array ( ) [5] => Array ( ) [6] => Array ( ) [7] => Array ( ) )
```

Can someone help me do this? I searched the solution a lot, but I couldn't find any information. I didn't know exactly how to search on the internet because my English isn't very good, thank you.

Comment: what is your input string? (seems to be a JSON)

Comment: Replace `#i` with `#si`. `.` does not match line breaks by default.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would say : use [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) instead of parsing JSON with RegEx

Comment: @Cid this string.. https://www.instagram.com/yourusername of source code..

Comment: @Cid Why tell that to me? I know that. Tell that OP.

Comment: @FazılAkbulut why giving a generic link to instagram ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew because I know you love RegEx a bit too much and looked like you were inviting OP to keep trying with RegEx instead of a proper way

Comment: I never use regex to parse JSON.

Comment: @FazılAkbulut please edit your question and show us both of your input and expected output

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's not a json. I get data from the source code of any instagram profile. view-source:https: //www.instagram.com/ziynetaki When you open the link you can see the following code.

<script type = "text / javascript"> window._sharedData = ..... </ script>

Comment: @AlwaysSunny I updated my question ..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm sorry, that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @FazılAkbulut This really is JSON, man.  [I've put it into a JSON editor](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=eba18e45283145e1957c4769d5cc71d6)

Comment: @Quixrick Actually you right. But i'm get this code from script tags.
Does this mean that there is a json? please look this ss. https://imgur.com/a/qScRr4X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex pattern has a small error due to which your match is failing.

Your regex has a `[` character in this part `{"edges":[{"node"` which you haven't escaped and hence that behaves as a character set and ruins the intended meaning of your regex.

Just escaping that `[` makes your pattern to start matching and giving expected results. Also, if your input spans across multiple lines, you can enable `DOTALL` mode to make `.` match new lines but as of now your input string doesn't require that and works as is.

**[Check here](https://regex101.com/r/8xOM6T/1)**

Check your PHP codes,

```
$url = '"edges":[{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"1998193948597745904","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"test"}}]},"shortcode":"Bu7As8ygPjw","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":0},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1552423302,"dimensions":{"height":216,"width":320},"display_url":"https://instagram.fdel1-4.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/b26fc82649aebaba80ff8750844d9476/5D32EFAE/t51.2885-15/e35/52508202_381950182383672_2887085630092404003_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fdel1-4.fna.fbcdn.net","edge_liked_by":{"count":6},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":6}';
$display = '#__typename":"GraphImage","id":"(.*?)","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":\[{"node":{"text":"(.*?)"}}]},"shortcode":"(.*?)","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":(.*?)},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":(.*?),"dimensions":{"height":(.*?),"width":(.*?)},"display_url":"(.*?)","edge_liked_by"#i';

preg_match_all($display, $url, $dop);
print_r($dop);
```

Prints all your intended captures,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => __typename":"GraphImage","id":"1998193948597745904","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"test"}}]},"shortcode":"Bu7As8ygPjw","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":0},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1552423302,"dimensions":{"height":216,"width":320},"display_url":"https://instagram.fdel1-4.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/b26fc82649aebaba80ff8750844d9476/5D32EFAE/t51.2885-15/e35/52508202_381950182383672_2887085630092404003_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fdel1-4.fna.fbcdn.net","edge_liked_by"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1998193948597745904
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bu7As8ygPjw
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1552423302
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 216
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 320
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://instagram.fdel1-4.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/b26fc82649aebaba80ff8750844d9476/5D32EFAE/t51.2885-15/e35/52508202_381950182383672_2887085630092404003_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fdel1-4.fna.fbcdn.net
        )

)
```

**[Online PHP Demo](https://rextester.com/GRMYX19665)**

Comment: Really thank you so much. This code worked fine. I'm thankful to you. (Clap, Clap, Clap.. 1 billion Clap :)))

Comment: Haha so glad to help :)